# cosmosdb mongo api not working for some commands

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using **cosmosdb** on azure
In that I am using **mongodb api**
I have a **"request"** collection inside that there is a **"claims"** array

If I use this command:

```
db.getCollection('requests').find({"claims.id": 1002})
```

It is not working in cosmosdb mongo api but working for local mongo service instance I have hosted.

my request object is as below

```json
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1001),
    "claims" : [ {
            "type" : "broadband",
            "id" : NumberLong(1002),
            "createdOn" : NumberLong(1462799667905)
              } ]
}
```

Comment: Your code seems mess (as in format), please see how you can enhance its look.

Answer (score 2):

Not all of MongoDB's query syntax / capabilities are implemented. This appears to be such a case.

However, this slight workaround should work for you - I just tested it on my own CosmosDB (MongoDB API) collection:

```
db.getCollection('request').find({claims: { $elemMatch: { id:1002 }}}).pretty()
{
  "_id" : 1001,
  "claims" : [
    {
      "type" : "broadband",
      "id" : 1002,
      "createdOn" : NumberLong("1462799667905")
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that you can also call `db.request.find()` without the need for a call to `getCollection()`.

Comment: David, can you please show the workaround how to update the object inside an array ?

Comment: Would be nice to know which if any are implemented :)