# cosmos db api for mongo db facing issue for some commands

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am using azure cosmosdb mongo api and unable to run bellow command on it. It runs fine when executed on locally hosted mongo service. Is there any way around for this?

```
db.getCollection('requests').update(
 {claims: { $elemMatch: { id:1000 }}},
 {$set:{"claims.$.billForMonth":"1"}}
)
```

My data is

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1000),
    "location" : "pune",
    "claims" : [ 
        {
            "id" : NumberLong(1000),
            "type" : "broadband",
            "billForMonth" : 4
        }]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cosmosdb mongo api not working for some commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587440/cosmosdb-mongo-api-not-working-for-some-commands)

Comment: That link is regarding a different command,I am not able to find alternative to this particular update command

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the issue on my side, when I do the following update operatation, it indicates I have updated the data successfully.

[image]

But if I query the data, I find `billForMonth` is not updated.

[image]

If I update a non-array field (such as `location` field), it works fine.

```
db.testc1.update(
 {claims: { $elemMatch: { id:1000 }}},
 {$set:{"location":"pune1"}}
)
```

It seems that cosmos db:mongo api does not support ***Array Update*** now, this feature will be supported in future. You will find the following information in [this article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-guidelines.md).

[image]