# (AZURE cosmosDB/mongoDB) Update fields of an specific element of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59660d4099c1e682e0992ced"),
    "alpha" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59660d4199c1e682e0992cee"),
            "number" : 1,
            "start_at" : ISODate("2017-07-12T11:51:28.895Z"),
            "end_at" : ISODate("2017-08-12T11:51:28.895Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-12T11:51:29.346Z"),
            "updated_at" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a document as above and I would like to update or change the field 'number' and 'updated_at' in a JSON element of 'alpha' array.

I tried this:

```
db.mycol.update({_id: ObjectId("59660d4099c1e682e0992ced"), alpha: {$elemMatch: {_id: ObjectId("59660d4199c1e682e0992cee")}}}, {$set: {"alpha.$.number": 2, "alpha.$.updated_at": new Date()}})
```

**It works fine with normal mongodb server. 
But with azure cosmosdb/mongodb it says ok but doesn't really update the document. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Prataksha, did you find any work around ?

Comment: well yeah, first I fetched the whole **alpha** array then I iterate through it and change the data I want to change. And finally After I am done I **$set** the **alpha** array again with an new updated values. I know it wont be like fully atomic like **findAndModify** but for now it does that job. Waiting for the full support by AZURE.

Answer (score 3):

> update or change the field 'number' and 'updated_at' in a JSON element of 'alpha' array

Not all of MongoDB's query syntax / capabilities are implemented in Azure Cosmos DB: MongoDB API. [Based on my test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633843/cosmos-db-api-for-mongo-db-facing-issue-for-some-commands), It seems that Azure Cosmos DB: MongoDB API does not support **Array Update** now, this feature will be supported in future.

[image]

If possible, you can create an item on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api) to give a feedback.

Comment: Please note that we have made some more progress on the supported CRUD and query operations and the table above does not currently reflect that is supported / will be supported.  And as Fred noted, for any query syntax and capabilities that do not appear to be implemented yet, please do provide feedback via [Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api).

Comment: @DennyLee Is there any documentation as to what features Azure Cosmos Db supports and does not support in regards to the Mongo API?

Comment: Not yet though we're working on this and will release soon.

Comment: @DennyLee Apparently not.

Comment: @DennyLee so you're asking people to vote if they do or do not want to have basic syntax implemented? now, how funny is that?

Comment: this is probably just to make people spend more because more round trips and more complicated queries just build up request charge. i see no other logical explanation to it.